# NIFI processor connector L shape

Tags: apache-nifi

New to NIFI, few flowfiles I have seen, there two processor are connected like L shape, I want to understand how change the arrow representation in NIFI. Mine is always straight line or slanting lines..
example / or \ or |

I need L shape or <

how to do it ?

Tried with shift but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Bending Connections](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#bending-connections)

To add a bend point (or elbow) to an existing connection, simply double-click on the connection in the spot where you want the bend point to be. Then, you can use the mouse to grab the bend point and drag it so that the connection is bent in the desired way. You can add as many bend points as you want. You can also use the mouse to drag and move the label on the connection to any existing bend point. To remove a bend point, simply double-click it again.

[image: Bending]